# Keep original head row when transposing twice with pgfplotstables

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm trying to add rows to an existing `pgfplotstables`.

So I'm using the method using twice `pgfplotstabletranspose`.
But it adds a new head row. I would like to delete it in order to keep the original one when i'm transposing the table a second time.

I read the manual and didnt find anything about this.

Comment: It's probably an option for \pgfplottabletranspose, but can't tell for sure without experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you wind up with an extra column, but those are easy to ignore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{%
a b c d
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\pgfplotstabletranspose{\newtable}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\newtable}

\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=colnames,input colnames to=index]{\retable}{\newtable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\retable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Can you explain to me why this is working ? Thanks !

Comment: Without [colnames from=] it generate new column names colnames,0,1,2,...  With [colnames from=colnames] it uses the entries from colnames for the head row and does not include the column in the transpose otherwise.